# Selective compilation

Tags: programming-languages

I'm wondering is there a capability, in any programming language, that I can choose to compile only a certain part of code. See example below.

This is a block of pseudocode:

```
function foo() {

    if (isDebug) {
      checkSomethingForDebugging();
      print(some debug info);
    }

    toSomeFooThings();
}
```

This block is for debugging purpose, I want to ignore them (even the if statement) in production.

```
if (isDebug) {
  checkSomethingForDebugging();
  print(some debug info);
}
```

One thing I can do is to comment out these lines,

```
function foo() {

    //if (isDebug) {
    //  checkSomethingForDebugging();
    //  print(some debug info);
    //}

    toSomeFooThings();
}
```

But what if I have thousands of places like this? It will be good if there is a way (a flag) that I can choose to compile a certain part of the code or not. It's like a `debugging build`. Is there anything for this in any programming language? I did search online but was no luck.

Comment: You should look at interpretive languages, like BASIC.  Each line is interpreted (translated & executed) separately.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Like python? How can I achieve this in a py file?

Comment: Python is not interpreted; it is compiled to byte code, which is then executed by a virtual machine.

Comment: One solution may be to run your code through a pre processor to convert it to the final code that you want to compile/run. The C pre processor (cpp) might work for you, but is not intended as general purpose tool. m4 may be a better choice as it is more general.

Comment: You are treating this as for *all* or *any* languages.  There are a **lot** of languages that you didn't tag, such as LISP and FORTRAN.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most languages don't have this, but you could certainly write a script which processed the source code somewhere in your build/deploy pipeline and deleted the debug only parts. An advanced way would be to properly parse the source code and delete the appropriate `if` blocks. For Python this would be quite easy using either the `ast` module or just looking for lines saying `if is_debug:` and then watching the indentation level. For other languages it might be harder. A simpler way in terms of the preprocessing script would be to use delimiting comments:

```
// DEBUGONLY
checkSomethingForDebugging();
print(some debug info);
// ENDDEBUGONLY
```

In this case the `if` statement is optional depending on how exactly you want to do things.

Comment: I think I learnt the concept of preprocessing, which can be general to all programming languages. Thanks.

Comment: Yelp!'s Undebt project (https://github.com/Yelp/undebt) might be of use in this effort.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on the compiler you are using. For example, in GCC for the C programming language, you have a whole set of preprocessor instructions that could be used for that.

For example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
// Your code here...
#endif /* DEBUG */
```

And, when you are compiling the debug version, you just have to include an extra header that defines the DEBUG macro. There's no need of setting any value, just define it.

```
#define DEBUG
```

And that's it.

Comment: If I'm compiling a non-debug version, will these part of code being compiled at all? I'm not only asking the code block inside `ifdef`, but also the `ifdef` check itself.

Comment: The ifdef check is not part of the program. The C compiler runs two times. The first one, executes the preprocessor instructions. In that run, it will decide if it has to compile the code inside the #ifdef check. The second time executes over the result of the first. So if the first excludes the code, it won't be in the final binary file.

Comment: Better wording, Javier: Compiler runs once, but it has multiple stages.

Comment: @JavierPazSedano ok, looks like what's I'm asking is achievable in C

Comment: @mattsun It's a stand alone preprocessor, you could use it the preprocess any source file, no matter the language.

Comment: Note that the C preprocessor also eliminates comments. So if you're e.g. running the C preprocessor on an XML file that contains URLs, they will break, because `<string>http://example.com</string>` looks like it has a comment in the middle, so that will be removed and you're left with `<string>http:` on that line, which is an opening tag without a closing tag, so not valid XML anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are languages (including C, C++ and C#) that can do this using preprocessor directives like `#if` or `#ifdef`:

```cs
#if DEBUG
checkSomethingForDebugging();
print(some debug info);
#endif
```

When the code is compiled, if the `DEBUG` symbol is not set, the code between the two directives is not compiled at all (and doesn't even have to be valid code).

But more importantly, why are you asking? If you're worried about performance, then such checks are very cheap (since they are easily predicted). And if the checks are written right (e.g. if `isDebug` is a global constant) and compiled using a good compiler, [they can even be eliminated as dead code](https://godbolt.org/g/CkuLMX), which makes them completely free.

Comment: You are right, performance is my concern. But I also understand that it's very cheap to do a if check.